# How can I ensure that ProGuard keeps all my own classes in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, proguard, android-proguard

I'm having a problem with ProGuard removing my own classes. I have created a proguard.cfg where I try to specify -keep class for them, but I can only get it working when specifying the classes with their md5 hashed package.

For example, the package name for my application is se.initech.foo, and I have a class in a sub-package Framework, called InfoBox.
So I would expect the fully qualified class name to be `se.initech.foo.Framework.InfoBox`.

But after I compile and package and run ProGuard, in the application output log I can see that it can't find the class `md586c878b9e5eee7e17627db5c3cd60647.InfoBox`.

And if I add

```
-keep class md586c878b9e5eee7e17627db5c3cd60647.** { *; }
```

to my proguard.cfg file, it works. However, if I try to specify the real class name, i.e. `se.initech.foo.**` or even `se.initech.foo.Framwork.InfoBox`, it doesn't work.

Is there a way to

a) use the real package name of the classes in proguard.cfg, or

b) find out the hashes beforehand, and not only by inspecting the crashes in the application output log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin auto-generates a `proguard_xamarin.cfg` that includes your project classes (it will be in your `obj` artifact directory):

#### `proguard_xamarin.cfg` Example:

```
~~~~
-keep class md52ce486a14f4bcd95899665e9d932190b.** { *; <init>(...); }
-keepclassmembers class md52ce486a14f4bcd95899665e9d932190b.** { *; <init>(...); }
~~~~
```

It will also create a `proguard_project_references.cfg` that includes all the Android Callable Wrapper (ACW) classes that your project creates.

If you do not want to Xamarin to auto-create MD5-based class names, you will need to manually assign a `Name` via class attributes (`~~~~Attribute`), i.e.:

#### `ActivityAttribute` `Name`:

```
[Activity(Name = "com.sushhangover.proguarddroid.StackOverflowActivity", Label = "ProGuardDroid", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@mipmap/icon")]
```

#### `BroadcastReceiverAttribute` `Name`:

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Name = "com.sushhangover.proguarddroid.SOBroadcastReceiver")]
public class SOBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
```

Comment: But doesn’t that only keep my names for Activities? The classes I have problems with are a Fragment and a layout component that inherits from LinearLayout. I tried registering my activities by name by using [Activity(Name = “se.initech.blue.MyActivity”)], and in the generated file proguard_project_primary.cfg I can see that my activities are kept with their nice names, but everything else is stil hashed...

Comment: Never mind, I realised that I can use the same method on any class by using 
`[Register(se.initech.foo.MyClass)]`

Comment: @JohanDriessen For any ACW-based classes that you do not want to use the auto-MD5 naming, you would need to supply a hard-coded `Name` to each and everyone of them. ACW-based classes should be auto added within the `proguard_project_references.cfg`. I know that inner classes will not be auto-added and have to be manually added to a custom proguard file in your project, I filed a bug concerning this that has gone no-where ;-(.